# Angular - resolving for multiple controllers in the same view/route/page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

We are building a big SPA , currently the app is build with `widgets/components`. each with a template, controller. but many can be nested in the same route.  for example: In the route `/users/` I can have a `` `userCtrl `` and a `userTemplate`that renders the user stats parts. a `graphCtrl` and a `graphTemplate` to render some d3 graphs. a `listCtrl` and a `listTemplate` to render a list. all of those widgets should be reusable (with different css and layouts, sometimes with the same ctrl different templates in other pages).  I need to instantiate some  data from a service - Lets say a service that return my user id and more validations. so in the main app routing i define a `resolve{myId: function(srvname){return srvname.myId}}` for `userCtrl` route which the `when` clause of `routeProvider` routes to.

My problem is that `listCtrl` doesn't wait for `userCtrl` (the `main` page ctrl , which gets the route) to resolve the different promises, and then fails with missing data.

Is there a way to define the same resolve for multiple controllers, that some of them aren't a direct route target but more of (very) big component? Is there a better/smarter way to do this?

I know I can use directive for that. but moving the bussiness logic from `listCtrl` to a directive looks plain wrong.

I'll be glad for any help and advice

Answer (score 1):

The standard advice for communicating between controllers is to use a service.  If I'm reading your description right, then in your case the top-level controller would be responsible for setting up the model and setting it in the service for the "descendant" controllers to read.

**Edit** for @alonisser's comment:

You should be able to data-bind the dependent controller's view to a function on the dependent $scope (say `viewData()` in such a way that if the function returns null, the element is hidden or shows a "spinner" UI.

The dependent template would look something like:

```
...
<div data-ng-if="viewData() !== null">
    <!-- show display elements based on the return value from viewData() -->
</div>
...
```

The setup for `viewData` would look something like this:

```
...
$scope.viewData = function() {
    if ($scope.model.asyncData === null) {
        $log.info("no data yet!");
        return null;
    }
    else
        return prepare_for_view($scope.model.asyncData);
}
...
```

And the async calls in the userCtrl look something like:

```
something_that_returns_a_promise.then(function (result) {
    $scope.model.asyncData = result;
});
```

A key piece is that the `something_that_returns_a_promise()` has to be something "inside" the AngularJS call stack, for example done using `$http`.  When that's the case, Angular automatically calls `$scope.$apply()`, and your dependent display elements should update seamlessly.  Otherwise you will need to call `$scope.$apply()` yourself in the async callback that sets `$scope.model.asyncData`.

Comment: thanks @david-pope but I think you are missing the point here, the top level controller does set the model. but since the async operations involved the other controllers don't wait for it and just fail. ''' resolving''' would do the trick, but the controllers just run without waiting for the ```top-level``` controller to resolve. I s there a way to force them to?